# Plot ROC curve from Cross-Validation (training) data in R

Tags: r, r-caret, roc, auc

I would like to know if there is a way to plot the average ROC Curve from the cross-validation data of a SVM-RFE model generated with the `caret` package.

My results are:

```
Recursive feature selection

Outer resampling method: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 5 times) 

Resampling performance over subset size:

 Variables    ROC   Sens   Spec Accuracy  Kappa  ROCSD SensSD SpecSD AccuracySD KappaSD Selected
         1 0.6911 0.0000 1.0000   0.5900 0.0000 0.2186 0.0000 0.0000     0.0303  0.0000         
         2 0.7600 0.3700 0.8067   0.6280 0.1807 0.1883 0.3182 0.2139     0.1464  0.3295         
         3 0.7267 0.4233 0.8667   0.6873 0.3012 0.2020 0.3216 0.1905     0.1516  0.3447         
         4 0.6989 0.3867 0.8600   0.6680 0.2551 0.2130 0.3184 0.1793     0.1458  0.3336         
         5 0.7000 0.3367 0.8600   0.6473 0.2006 0.2073 0.3359 0.1793     0.1588  0.3672         
         6 0.7167 0.3833 0.8200   0.6427 0.2105 0.1909 0.3338 0.2539     0.1682  0.3639         
         7 0.7122 0.3767 0.8333   0.6487 0.2169 0.1784 0.3226 0.2048     0.1642  0.3702         
         8 0.7144 0.4233 0.7933   0.6440 0.2218 0.2017 0.3454 0.2599     0.1766  0.3770         
         9 0.8356 0.6533 0.7867   0.7300 0.4363 0.1706 0.3415 0.2498     0.1997  0.4209         
        10 0.8811 0.6867 0.8200   0.7647 0.5065 0.1650 0.3134 0.2152     0.1949  0.4053        *
        11 0.8700 0.6933 0.8133   0.7627 0.5046 0.1697 0.3183 0.2147     0.1971  0.4091         
        12 0.8678 0.6967 0.7733   0.7407 0.4682 0.1579 0.3153 0.2559     

...
The top 5 variables (out of 10):
   SumAverage_GLCM_R1SC4NG2, Variance_GLCM_R1SC4NG2, HGZE_GLSZM_R1SC4NG2, LGZE_GLSZM_R1SC4NG2, SZLGE_GLSZM_R1SC4NG2
```

I have tried with the solution mentioned here:
[ROC curve from training data in caret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31138751/roc-curve-from-training-data-in-caret)

```
optSize <- svmRFE_NG2$optsize
selectedIndices <- svmRFE_NG2$pred$Variables == optSize
plot.roc(svmRFE_NG2$pred$obs[selectedIndices],
         svmRFE_NG2$pred$LUNG[selectedIndices])
```

But this solution seems not to work (the resulting AUC value is quite different). I have separated the results of the training process into the 50 cross-validation sets, as mentioned in the previous answer, but I do not know what to do next.

```
resamples<-split(svmRFE_NG2$pred,svmRFE_NG2$pred$Variables)
resamplesFOLD<-split(resamples[[optSize]],resamples[[optSize]]$Resample)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you already did you can a) enable `savePredictions = T` in the `trainControl` parameter of `caret::train`, then, b) from the trained model object, use the `pred` variable - which contains all predictions over all partitions and resamples - to compute whichever ROC curve you would like to look at. You now have multiple options of which ROC this can be, e.g.:

you could look at **all predictions over all partitions and resamples at once**:

```
plot(roc(predictor = modelObject$pred$CLASSNAME, response = modelObject$pred$obs))
```

Or you could do this over **individual partitions and/or resamples** (which is what you tried above). The following example computes the ROC curve per partition *and* resample, so with 10 partitions and 5 repeats will result in 50 ROC curves:

```
library(plyr)
l_ply(split(modelObject$pred, modelObject$pred$Resample), function(d) {
    plot(roc(predictor = d$CLASSNAME, response = d$obs))
})
```

Depending on your data and model, the latter *will* give you certain variance in the resulting ROC curves and AUC values. You can see the same variance in the `AUC` and `SD` values `caret` calculated for your individual partitions and resamples, so this results from your data and model and is correct.

BTW: I was using the `pROC::roc` function for calculating the examples above, but you could use any suitable function here. And, when using `caret::train` obtaining the ROC is always the same, no matter the model type.

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is old but I have the same issue trying to understand why I get different results when calculating the ROC value from each resample and when I am calculating the ROC value using all predictions and resamples at once. Which method for calculating ROC is correct?

(Apologies for posting this as a new answer but I am not allowed to post a comment.)