# How to plot AUC ROC for different caret training models?

Tags: r, roc

Here's a reprex

```
library(caret)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(88, sample.kind = "Rounding")

mtcars <- mtcars %>%
  mutate(am = as.factor(am))

test_index <- createDataPartition(mtcars$am, times = 1, p= 0.2, list = F)

train_cars <- mtcars[-test_index,]

test_cars <- mtcars[test_index,]

set.seed(88, sample.kind = "Rounding")
cars_nb <- train(am ~ mpg + cyl,
                data = train_cars, method = "nb", 
                trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10, savePredictions = "final"))

cars_glm <- train(am ~ mpg + cyl,
                 data = train_cars, method = "glm", 
                 trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10, savePredictions = "final"))
```

My question is, how would I go about creating an AUC ROC curve on a single plot to visually compare the two models?

Comment: could this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31138751/roc-curve-from-training-data-in-caret

Comment: Thanks for the link! the only thing I don't really understand in the answer is why is the parameter-setting set to 2?

Comment: mtry: Number of variables randomly sampled as candidates at each split (https://machinelearningmastery.com/tune-machine-learning-algorithms-in-r/)

Comment: Doesn't this only apply to random forest models?

Comment: I have no clue, but what does the output say?

Comment: I tried the MLeval method below, but the nb model doesn't output a probability dataframe from the train function

Comment: The first `train` fails with the following error for me: `Error: wrong model type for regression`

Comment: ... until I load dplyr. Then it works. I edited the question accordingly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume that you want to show the ROC curves on the test set, unlike in the question pointed in the comment ([ROC curve from training data in caret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31138751/roc-curve-from-training-data-in-caret)) which uses the training data.

The first thing to do will be to extract predictions on the test data (`newdata=test_cars`), in the form of probabilities (`type="prob"`):

```
predictions_nb <- predict(cars_nb, newdata=test_cars, type="prob")
predictions_glm <- predict(cars_glm, newdata=test_cars, type="prob")
```

This gives us a data.frame with probabilities to belong to class 0 or 1. Let's use the probability of class 1 only:

```
predictions_nb <- predict(cars_nb, newdata=test_cars, type="prob")[,"1"]
predictions_glm <- predict(cars_glm, newdata=test_cars, type="prob")[,"1"]
```

Next I'll use the pROC package to create the ROC curves for the training data (disclaimer: I am the author of this package. There are other ways to achieve the result, but this is the one I am the most familiar with):

```
library(pROC)
roc_nb <- roc(test_cars$am, predictions_nb)
roc_glm <- roc(test_cars$am, predictions_glm)
```

Finally you can plot the curves. To have two curves with the pROC package, use the `lines` function to add the line of the second ROC curve to the plot

```
plot(roc_nb, col="green")
lines(roc_glm, col="blue")
```

To make it more readable you can add a legend:

```
legend("bottomright", col=c("green", "blue"), legend=c("NB", "GLM"), lty=1)
```

And with the AUC:

```
legend_nb <- sprintf("NB (AUC: %.2f)", auc(roc_nb))
legend_glm <- sprintf("GLM (AUC: %.2f)", auc(roc_glm))
legend("bottomright",
       col=c("green", "blue"), lty=1,
       legend=c(legend_nb, legend_glm))
```

[image: ROC curves]

Comment: Thank you very much for the insightful answer @Calimo, I'm going to use your method instead of the MLeval the evalm function does ask to put a caret training result in. Is there any way one could add the AUC value to the curve?

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll use your plot.roc function!

Comment: Please remember to accept this answer if it solved your problem.